# Redirection 301 from prestashop category and product links (source) to woocommerce product and product links (target)

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce, prestashop

Do I need to permanently 301 redirect the category and product links of the prestashop source site to the category and product links of the woocommerce recipient site?

SOURCE CATEGORY LINK:

https://sourcedomain.com/3-accessori-e-utensili

REdirect TO RECIPIENT SITE:

https://targetdomain.com/home/accessori-e-utensili/

Searching the web I found this solution which is good for redirecting folders:

RedirectMatch 301 ^/3-accessori-e-utensili/.*$ https://targetdomain.com/home/accessori-e-utensili/

But I also need that the link of a product found on the source of the same category can point to the link on the recipient:
EXAMPLE

SOURCE PRODUCT LINK:

https://sourcedomain.com/accessori-e-utensili/907-lid-in-glass-sughiera-con-hole-cm28-8010111047254.html

RECIPIENT PRODUCT LINK:

https://targetdomain.com/home/accessori-e-utensili/coperchio-in-vetro-sughiera-con-foro-cm28/

Thank you all.

I expect a resolution on how to set the code in the .htaccess file

Comment: It looks like your old and new product URLs have little in common, so you will have to set up a rewrite for each one individually. If you have more than a handful products you need this for, then this should probably not all be hacked into the .htaccess to begin with, you should rather use a redirection plugin on the WordPress side ...